# Need to know how to change ip address and hostname after deploying OVF template

Tags: vmware-esx, deployment, template, ovf

In ESX, I export OVF of my VM (configured as dhcp). Then In another ESX, I use "deploy OVF template" from file menu. My new VM appears working, except I could not change the IP address and hostname.

VM: GuestOS: CentOS5.4 + my application

In the new VM's summary tub,
IP Addresses: (dhcp address)
DNS : xx-a50055

I changed:

/etc/sysconfig/network
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

I could not figure out what I have missed.

Thanks

Comment: Does it give you an error when you tried to change the IP address and host name? Can you paste the contents of the ifcfg-eth0 as well as the output of ifconfig -a?

Comment: Is this Ubuntu or another Debian based version of Linux?

Answer (score 1):

A deployed OVF often creates a new network interface, possibly `ifcfg-eth1`. This is because `udev` rules often bind a MAC address to name of the NIC. You can verify this by having a look at `/etc/udev/rules.d/*-persistent-net.rules`.

I can recommend two solutions:

1. You either delete `/etc/udev/rules.d/*-persistent-net.rules` before you export, or
2. you deploy as OVF and adapt `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1` (or whatever the new interface config file is called) to provide a static IP.